# How to get html content of web page from command prompt

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, webserver, html

I need to get html content of a web page that I need to run from command prompt Is it possible to get open a web page and also to get html content of that web page by running from command prompt?

Comment: Do you want to extract the html of a web page that is already opened in the browser? Please explain in more detail what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wget` (you may have to `sudo apt install wget`).

```
   GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web.  It
   supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as retrieval through HTTP proxies.
```